# Using groupby in groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows

```
user_id HouseNo      Name   location_id
 1     0-0        aaa    1
 2     0-0        bbb    1
 3     0-1        ccc    1
 4     1-2        ddd    1
 5     2-1        eee    1
 6     1-2        fff    1
 7     2-1        ggg    1
 8     1-2        hhh    1
 9     2-1        iii    1
 10    3-0        jjj    1
 11    3-0        kkk    1
 12    3-0        lll    1
```

I have 2 questions here

1)I need to get no of users by house no.For that i used 
   select house_no,count(user_id) from user group by house_no;

Then i got the result

```
    house_no count(house_no)
    0-0        2
    0-1        1
    1-2        3
    2-1        3
    3-0        3
```

It is fine for me.

But my question is how i can get the no of families which has count 1 and the no of families which has count 2 ......

```
Like as follows:


 count1   1
 count2   1
 count3   3
```

Here count1 means no of families having one user,count2 means no of families having two users......

> I have 3 fixed conditions here.They are   count<=3   count >4 and
>   count<10   count >10

I need the result like as follows

```
count1   count2 count3
1         1       3
```

NOTE:Here same family means users containing same houseno.
  Please help me...Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below has two parts, the first part is the subquery which calculates the Number of members per `House_No`. The result of the subquery is then calculated again and this time it will be group as the number of member.

```
SELECT  CONCAT('COUNT', totalMember) FamilyMember, COUNT(*) NumberOfFamilies
FROM
        (
            SELECT  House_No, COUNT(*) totalMember
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY House_no
        ) x
GROUP   BY totalMember
ORDER   BY totalMember
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3e338/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ FAMILYMEMBER ║ NUMBEROFFAMILIES ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ COUNT1       ║                1 ║
║ COUNT2       ║                1 ║
║ COUNT3       ║                3 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

To list families with N members, you can use [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) `GROUP BY` modifiers.

For families with 1 member :

```
SELECT Name, count(*) as c FROM Tablename GROUP BY Name HAVING c=1;
```

For families with 2 members :

```
SELECT Name, count(*) as c FROM Tablename GROUP BY Name HAVING c=2;
```

etc.