# Using multiple group by having in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have 2 queries to get the count of families having count = 1 and count = 2.

```
SELECT Name, count(*) as c FROM Tablename GROUP BY HOUSE_NO HAVING c<=1;


 SELECT Name, count(*) as c FROM Tablename GROUP BY  HOUSE_NO HAVING c>=2 and c<=4;
```

But i need to combine those queries into single query.Like

```
         count1                          count2
  nooffamiliesHavingcount = 1        nooffamiliesHavingcount = 2
```

Please help me....Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your first count into a subquery:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN C = 2 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount2
FROM    (   SELECT  COUNT(*) AS C
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP BY House_No
        ) t
WHERE   c IN (1, 2);
```

**EDIT**

If you need to do ranges in your count you can use this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN C <= 1 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN C BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount2,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount3
FROM    (   SELECT  COUNT(*) AS C
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP BY House_No
        ) t
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd7ad/1)**

Comment: can i specify condition here .That is in IN

Comment: here for example i specified 1 and 2.

Comment: but i have conditions like <=1 , >=2 and <=10 , above10.

Comment: see my previous question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806022/using-groupby-in-groupby/15806076

Comment: If the count is wrong it is because your question is misleading. The two queries you have posted return 12 and 0 results respectively, the query I have posted above returns 12, 0, 0. So exactly matches your results. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3e338/19

Comment: why 12 is coming for nooffamiliesHavingcount1

Comment: Because there are 12 different families in your table, and they each just have 1 row.

Comment: the result is 1 because the no of families having count<=1 is 1

Comment: because in the sample data there is 12 different values of Name (aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg, hhh, iii, jjj, kkk, lll), I suspect that you actually want to group by `house_no` and not name. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd7ad/1

Comment: i am really sorry .It is not group by name it is house_no

Comment: now it is working fine .Thank u so much.But i can accept only one answer.+1 for you

Comment: it is giving the result as i want

Comment: @GarethD is it possible to get the no of users in family in this same query

Comment: @GarethD i have 4,00,000 records in my table .It is taking too much time .What i have to do.I am getting server gone away error

Comment: Create an index on `House_No`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c <= 1 THEN "<=1"
            WHEN c BETWEEN 2 and 4 THEN "2-4"
       END familysize,
       COUNT(*) nooffamilies
FROM (SELECT Name, count(*) c
      FROM Tablename
      GROUP BY Name) x
GROUP BY familysize
HAVING familysize IS NOT NULL
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e0f1/3)